Set of extensors in $\Lambda^k(V)$ coincides with the affine algebraic variety defined by the ideal $I_{d,k} = ker(\phi_{d,k})$
I am reading Sturmfel's book Algorithms in Invariant Theory.
They use the following notations: $\Lambda(n,d):= \{[\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_d] | 1 \leq \lambda_1 < \lambda_2 \leq \cdots < \lambda_d \leq \lambda_n\}$
and 
There is the following.

It are 2 really basic questions, but I am confused:

How does the choice of basis identifies the ring of polynomial functions on $\Lambda^k(V)$ with the polynomial ring $C[\Lambda(d,k)]$? Is it correct that we associate $e_{j_1} \vee \cdots \vee e_{j_k}$ with $[j_1 \cdots j_k]$?
Why does the set of extensors in $\Lambda^k(V)$ coincide with the affine algebraic variety defined by the ideal $I_{d,k}$? I just do not see why this is true.


What is $[\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_d]$?

$d$ is the dimension and $[\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_d] = det(\begin{pmatrix}
x_{\lambda_1 1}       & x_{\lambda_1 2} & x_{\lambda_13} & \dots & x_{\lambda_1d} \
x_{\lambda_21}       & x_{\lambda_22} & x_{\lambda_23} & \dots & x_{\lambda_2d} \
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \
x_{\lambda_d 1}       & x_{\lambda_d2} & x_{\lambda_d3} & \dots & x_{\lambda_dd}
\end{pmatrix})$

So $\varphi$ is essentially the identity...?

$C[\lambda(n,d)]$ works formally with the brackets, while in $C[x_{ij}]$, the brackets are worked out.

$
\newcommand\form[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
$I have to say that this is a strange way to handle the exterior algebra, and I've never heard the term "extensor" for what are usually called simple multivectors or blades.
The following is what I was able to hammer out, there may be a better way to present the same ideas.

The ring of polynomial functions on $\Lambda^k(V)$ is the symmetric algebra $S(\Lambda^k(V)^*)$. A map $S(\Lambda^k(V)^*) \to \mathbf C[\Lambda(d,k)]$ is uniquely determined by its action on $\Lambda^k(V)^*$ which is naturally identified with alternating $k$-linear forms. A basis for $\Lambda^k(V)$ gives a corresponding dual basis for $\Lambda^k(V)^*$ which are Sturmfel's $a$ determinants; that is to say that corresponding to $e_{j_1}\vee\dotsb\vee e_{j_k}$ we have $\psi_{j_1\dotsb j_k} \in \Lambda^k(V)^*$ given by
$$
  \psi_{j_1\dotsb j_k}(a_1\vee\dotsb\vee a_k) = \begin{vmatrix}
    a_{1j_1} & a_{1j_2} & \cdots & a_{1j_k} \\
    a_{2j_1} & a_{2j_2} & \cdots & a_{2j_k} \\
    \vdots   & \vdots   & \ddots & \vdots   \\
    a_{kj_1} & a_{kj_2} & \cdots & a_{kj_k}
  \end{vmatrix}.
$$
So all together we have a linear map $\Lambda^k(V)^* \to \mathbf C[\Lambda(d,k)]$ given by the "obvious" $\psi_{j_1\dotsb j_k} \mapsto [j_1\dotsb j_k]$, which uniquely determines a homomorphism $S(\Lambda^k(V)^*) \to \mathbf C[\Lambda(d,k)]$. Similarly a map $\mathbf C[\Lambda(d,k)] \to S(\Lambda^k(V)^*)$ is entirely determined by its action on $[j_1\dotsb j_k]$, so we easily get an inverse and have an isomorphism $S(\Lambda^k(V)^*) \cong \mathbf C[\Lambda(d,k)]$.

To associate the map $\iota : V^k \to \Lambda^k(V)$ with $\phi_{d,k}$, first take its dual $\Lambda^k(V)^* \to (V^k)^*$. We can think of this as a map
$$
  \Lambda^k(V)^* \to (V^k)^* \subseteq S((V^*)^k) \cong \mathbf C[x_{ij}]
$$
where the last isomorphism follows from choosing a basis for $V$. This naturally extends to a map $\phi'_{d,k} : S(\Lambda^k(V)^*) \to \mathbf C[x_{ij}]$, and I claim $\phi'_{d,k} = \phi_{d,k}$. To see this, evaluate on $\psi_{j_1\dotsb j_k}$:
$$
  \psi_{j_1\dotsb j_k}
  \mapsto \psi_{j_1\dotsb j_k}\circ\iota
  \mapsto \psi_{j_1\dotsb j_k}\circ\iota\left(
    \begin{pmatrix}x_{11}\\x_{12}\\\vdots\\x_{1d}\end{pmatrix},
    \begin{pmatrix}x_{21}\\x_{22}\\\vdots\\x_{2d}\end{pmatrix},
    \dotsc,
    \begin{pmatrix}x_{k1}\\x_{k2}\\\vdots\\x_{kd}\end{pmatrix}
  \right)
  = \begin{vmatrix}
    x_{1j_1} & x_{1j_2} & \cdots & x_{1j_k} \\
    x_{2j_1} & x_{2j_2} & \cdots & x_{2j_k} \\
    \vdots   & \vdots   & \ddots & \vdots   \\
    x_{kj_1} & x_{kj_2} & \cdots & x_{kj_k}
  \end{vmatrix}.
$$
So we are interested in the kernel of the map $S(\Lambda^k(V)^*) \to S((V^k)^*)$. But $S(W^*) \cong S(W)^*$ for any $W$, so we can turn this into a question about the dual $\iota : S(V^k) \to S(\Lambda^k(V))$. If $\form{\cdot,\cdot}$ is the pairing $S(W^*) \times S(W) \to \mathbf C$ then for all $\psi \in S(\Lambda^k(V)^*)$ and $X \in S(V^k)$ we have
$$
  \form{\phi_{d,k}(\psi), X} = \form{\psi, \iota(X)}.
$$
Thus $\psi \in \ker(\phi_{d,k})$ iff $\form{\psi, Y} = 0$ for all $Y \in \mathrm{Im}(\iota)$. The image of $\iota$ is the subalgebra $E^k(V)$ of $S(\Lambda^k(V))$ generated by extensors.
The affine algebraic variety defined by $\ker(\phi_{d,k})$ is
$$
  \bigcap_{\psi\in\ker\phi_{d,k}}\{X \in S(\Lambda^k(V)) \;:\; \form{\psi, X} = 0\}.
$$
(In other words, the intersection of all the "solution sets" of the "polynomials" $\psi$.) Clearly this set contains $E^k(V)$. I am not sure yet why is must be $E^k(V)$ exactly.
